# Language Detection on Mobile Devices

Tags: mobile, language-detection

I am working on an application that needs to detect and switch languages. 
I have been looking for some best practices on how to properly do this on mobile devices.

If there wa way to access the phone (iphone, android, windows) and determine the language it is using? or should I be detecting the language based on mobile browser settings?

Any references y'all have would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Is this a website, a native app, a phonegap app, what?

Comment: it is going to be responsive websites and also facebook applications. Sorry should have specified that :)

Answer (score 0):

In general you can take a look at the Accept-Language HTTP header. For facebook applications, I believe the facebook SDK will provide the user's language preference as "locale" or similar in the user object.

Comment: Thanks!! Is there any way to see the language their phone is using. I know personally I think there is nothing more annoying then when I;m traveling and languages force me into something other than English because of my location rather than my typical settings

Comment: I believe the "Accept-Language" HTTP header will contain a list of preferred languages.